# Changing Language at Login doesn't do anything?

Tags: 11.04, language-support, locale

Whenever i am changing the language at the time of login,the language in the regional format doesn't change.Why does that happen?.

I am facing a very strange behavior in Ubuntu 11.04,
As in normal cases when ever we change language at the time of login its change its locale variable and it use to set that selected language as the default language in
"Text" tab of the Language Support up till the Ubuntu version 10.10,
But in Ubuntu 11.04 its not the case.
When ever we change the language at the time of login at that time the language is not set in the "Regional Formats" of the Language Support.So it is not changing
the LANG variable of the "locale" command in th Ubuntu.

So is it a bug or the change in behavior for the Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Language Support in the System Settings, you will notice that you got two tabs - Language and Regional Formats.

[image]

During your login, you selected a different language for menus and windows. However, your regional format didn't change. So for better user experience, change the settings through this Language Support.

In the Language tab, move the language that you want to the upper most. And if you want all user to have the same setting, click on 'Apply System-Wide'.

To have your numbers, date & currency in your regional format, you need to do that in the Regional Formats tab. Select the format that you want in the first combobox. You can choose to 'Apply System-Wide' if you wish to.

[image: Text tab in Language & Text]

Finally, you will have to logout and login again to have this new setting loaded.

Comment: Yes thats true.But in the Ubuntu 11.04 there are two tabs Language and Regional Formats.

Comment: So did it solved your problem? Perhaps the 'Language and Regional Formats' and 'Language and Text' is another localization issue?

Comment: Yes thats true.But in the Ubuntu 11.04 there are two tabs Language and Regional Formats.                                                            Now generally what happen is that when ever we chnage the langauge at the time of login that languauge is set as the language in the Regional Formats(In previous release of Ubuntu its know as Text).Which is set as the locale language which we can see by typing "locale" in terminal.So i question is that when ever i change the language at the time of login language in the Regional Fromats is not getting change which is not the expected behavior.

Comment: I guess in this case. It is either a bugs or a change in behaviour for Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Yes..it seems like a bug or change in behaviour but if its in chnage in behaviour i was not able to find any bug reported any where or neither i found any document related to this (say...) change in behaviour.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          If you know about such thing or if u able to find anything please let me know.

Comment: Thanks JohanSJA...@peter do know anything about this change...??

Comment: @JohanSJA...hey dude do u find anything information about this issue..??

Comment: @hardik ... Sorry, I didn't find anything to that.

Comment: Okay so could you just suggest me some names which might know something about this issue...Because its quite tricky and there is no such information available on Internet also.

Comment: I have no idea about this either.